# Cors error while trying to create mern app

Tags: reactjs, frontend, cors, backend, mern

Hi everyone i am trying to create a mern app and using cors but i am getting the following error
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/v2/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
Frontend function for login

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => async (dispatch: any) => {
    const header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4000',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }
    const response = await fetch(LOGIN_API, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: header,
        body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password})
    });
    const json: CommonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    if(json.success){
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: json.data });
    }
    else{
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: json.message })
    }
}
```

for backend -
app.ts

```
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/v2/auth', userRoute);
app.use('/v1/room', roomRoute);
app.use('/v1/messages', messageRoute);
app.use(ErrorMiddleware);

export default app;
```

and for routing and login function

```
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/login').post(loginWithEmail);
router.route('/signup').post(createUser);
router.route('/logout').post(authenticateUser, logout);
router.route('/me').get(authenticateUser, getUserDetails);
```

```
export const loginWithEmail = catchAsyncError( async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(email, password);
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
    if(user === null){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Credentials", 400));
    }
    const isPasswordHashed: boolean = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password!);
    if(!isPasswordHashed){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Credentials", 400));
    }

    const data: UserToken = {
        user:{
            id: user.id
        }
    }
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    sendToken(res, data, "Login Successful");
});
```

send token is a function which sets a cookie and sends data via response.

Comment: Does removing `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');` from `loginWithEmail` function help? You don't need to explicitly specify this header when you are configuring CORS. Express does it for you. Also can you inspect you response headers in the browser's network tab?

Comment: no i added this to solve this problem only but it does not work. no i am not getting response

Comment: Also `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'` this is a header for the backend to set, you don't need to set it in the frontend... Do read about `preflight` requests

Comment: Can you add the latest error and the latest code? as the error mentions a * (wildcard) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but the code shows a string value

Comment: sure i will do that

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255799/discussion-between-brahm-bind-singh-and-exter).

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to true, then `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be a wildcard. Therefore, you will need to specify the exact:

- protocol
- domain
- port

instead.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4000',
```

looks good if you un-comment it, but you will then need to make sure that it is indeed `http` (not some other protocol, like https) and it is indeed `localhost` (not some other domain) and 4000 (not some other port).

Of course, assuming that your request is successfully sent from **http://localhost:4000**, your request might still fail for other reasons. But it is definitely a step forward for fix your access control allow origin to something more tangible.